# Trying to derive from SMTPClient

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a CreateUserWizard, which if a MailDefinition is created on it, will look for the default SMTPClient as defined in the  configuration section.

I would like to use this configuration section, however the password I want to use is encrypted.

I am attempting to derive from SMTPClient(recommended by another generous poster in previous question) my attempt at implementing is below:

```
public class MySmtpClient: SmtpClient
    {
       public MySmtpClient() : base()
        {
            MySmtpClient mySmtpClient = new MySmtpClient();
            NetworkCredential nc = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            nc.Password = DecryptMyPassword(nc.Password);
            mySmtpClient.Credentials = nc;
```

I still haven't gotten that part working - but when I do - how do I make it so that the CreateUserWizard uses my derived object to send mail versus the default SMTPClient object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle `OnSendingMail` event of CreateUserWizard.

In the event handler, use `MySmtpClient` and cancel the default client by setting `e.Cancel = true;`

```
protected void CreateUserWizard_SendingMail(object sender, MailMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        //cancel default handling.
        e.Cancel = true;

        MySmtpClient myClient = new MySmtpClient();
        //fill details and send mail.
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Small improvement: `new MySmtpClient().Send(e.Message);`